# Polylines trazan una línea recta en Google Maps Android

Tags: android, c#, visual-studio, google-maps, xamarin

Estoy intentando crear una ruta de conducción a través de PolyLines:

```
    List<Position> RouteCoordinates = new List<Position>();
    RouteCoordinates.Add(new Position(37.7850268, -122.4005109));
    RouteCoordinates.Add(new Position(37.780624, -122.390541));

    var polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polylineOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

    foreach (var position in RouteCoordinates)
    {
        polylineOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
        gmap.AddMarker(marker);
    }

    gmap.AddPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

Pero el problema es que se crea una línea recta desde los dos puntos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Hay algún método para obtener las direcciones de conducción entre estos dos puntos?

Comment: Google places API se usa para obtener los datos, ve los datos de los marcadores en mi respuesta y Routing  traza la ruta de navegación entre los puntos, agregué respuesta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para hacer lo que quieres tienes que echar mano de [Google Maps Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=es-419). Basicamente, le das como parámetros el origen y el destino y te devuelve un json con mucha información, entre ella los `steps`(pasos) necesarios para ir de un sitio a otro. Dentro de cada `step` tienes una polilinea codificada ([aquí hay una implementación para decodificarla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656798/encoding-google-api-polyline-points-in-monodroid-c-sharp)) con cada paso. El proceso entonces se trata de recorrer cada paso y dibujar su polilinea (o polilineas, si no me equivoco un paso puede tener varias).

El proceso es algo laborioso, puedes echar un vistazo a alguna libreria que facilite el proceso ([esta por ejemplo parece que implementa el API](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap)).

Por ultimo decirte que el Google Maps Directions API tiene ciertas limitaciones, que son las siguientes:

- 2500 solicitudes de indicaciones gratuitas por día, calculadas como la suma de las consultas del cliente y el servidor.
- Hasta 23 waypoints permitidos por cada solicitud, así se trate de consultas del cliente o el servidor.
- 50 solicitudes por segundo, calculadas como la suma de las consultas del cliente y el servidor.

Espero que estas indicaciones te den una idea aproximada de lo necesario para realizar lo que quieres.

Comment: Tal vez es porque esta respuesta es como una respuesta con  comentarios.... =| , podrías agregar algo de código que has realizado para mostrarle al OP como implementar. Recuerda que SO no es un foro =(

Comment: [como escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer):_Cualquier respuesta que encamine al los lectores en la dirección correcta ayudara siempre y cuando menciones limitaciones, supuestos, o simplificaciones en tu respuesta._

Comment: ahh ok, excellent -- ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Puedo estar equivocado,ninguno estamos exentos de no tener razon. Tal vez abra una pregunta en meta a ver si la comunidad esta de acuerdo contigo y si es asi,eliminare mi respuesta y a la vez aprenderé algo nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Para trazar una ruta posible de conducción debes utilizar la **[API de Google Places](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start)**:

```
   mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();
```

defines los puntos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y por medio de la clase Routing de la APIm se crea una trayectoria de navegación:

```
        Routing routing = new Routing.Builder()
                .travelMode(AbstractRouting.TravelMode.DRIVING)
                .withListener(this)
                .waypoints(start, end)
                .build();
        routing.execute();
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te recomiendo revisar de la documentación:

[**Places API for Android**](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/)

Comment: Estaría por jurar que la API de Places no tiene ninguna opción para generar rutas. Estás seguro de tu respuesta? De hecho, la clase `Routing` que utilizas creo que no es una api standard, si no que diría que es [esta](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/README.md), que hace uso como digo en mi respuesta del Directions Api y que indica que el proyecto no esta siendo mantenido. Por último, OP busca una solucion para Xamarin, y la que tu das creo que es java...

Comment: Estas imágenes que agrego en mi respuesta son de un proyecto que realicé en Android, regularmente no busco algo hecho o una librería, ese proyecto que comentas no esta siendo mantenido no es un "proyecto" library, es una simple aplicación que cualquiera puede realizar,  por eso agrego mi respuesta. En cuanto a tu respuesta, el sitio de Stackoverflow es regularmente para responder técnicamente y tu respuesta es sumamente teorica, puede ser como varios comentarios.

Comment: Mi respuesta es posible que sea teorica,pero explica los pasos necesarios para realizar lo que pide el OP (que de hecho la ha aceptado). Tu respuesta en cambio es en mi opinion incorrecta,ya que la api de Google Places no tiene absolutamente nada que ver con dibujar una ruta,utiliza una librería externa que no indicas en tu respuesta y ademas es en Java,no en xamarin que es lo que se pedía :)

Comment: Los pasos necesarios?, si este sitio fuera lleno de respuestas teóricas probablemente sería un foro. En cuanto al OP si la acepto pues el decide que aceptar o no. Alguna vez has utilizado la API de Google Places ? si es de Xamarin porque agregar esto: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro?hl=es-419 en verdad has usado Xamarin ?

Comment: No voy a entrar en ninguna discusion contigo. Curiosamente me das un enlace apuntando a la documentacion del Directions Api y no de Google Places. Puedes darme algun enlace donde se diga que con Google Places Api se puede obtener una ruta para pintarla? Y si,he realizado aplicaciones tanto java como xamarin utilizando el directions api. Yo no voy a preguntartelo a ti,ya que veo que no vas a reconocer que estas equivocado. Un saludo y a seguir ayudando que de eso se trata.

Comment: El url es de tu respuesta haha. Google places API se usa para obtener los datos, ve los datos de los marcadores en mi respuesta y Routing  traza la ruta de navegación entre los puntos (⌐■_■)

Comment: No pensaba contestarte pero creo que yo te he tratado con educacion y tu a mi con bastante prepotencia. Los apis son los mismos sea xamarin o java,varía la forma de llamarlos de ahi que enlace a la documentacion. Se para que es Google Places y como ya te he dicho,es absolutamente irrelevante a la hora de dibujar una ruta. Y por ultimo,puedes darme algun enlace a la documentacion de `Routing`?

Comment: No se porque comentas que con prepotencia, puedes ver en el proyecto que dices "no ha sido mantenido" que precisamente usan Routing y RoutingListener, https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/com/directions/sample/MainActivity.java

Comment: Si no pretendías ser prepotente te pido mil disculpas,tal vez yo interpreté mal.`Routing` es una clase de el proyecto que enlazo,como puedes ver [aqui](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/directions/route/Routing.java). No forma parte de ningun api oficial de Google,si no que es un wrapper del Directions API, y por eso deduzco que en tu proyecto utilizas dicha libreria y por eso te dije que deberias especificarlo en tu respuesta. Por mi parte aqui acaba el tema,un saludo

Comment: Hola no te preocupes igualmente disculpas, pero en verdad nunca intente ni soy prepotente. saludos

Comment: Igualmente,a veces es dificil interpretar la intencion en un texto escrito. Por mi parte,ningun problema y a seguir siendo util aqui como eres. Saludos

Comment: Igualmente Pikoh, saludos! ᕦ ´• ᴥ •` ᕥ